# Using the fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I'm trying to set up a log in system for an app, and I've been following along with [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SIZBRCj5tc). Basically I understand the general concept of what's going on, but not why he's doing what he's doing sometimes. Anyways, I get some errors with the lines that say

```
final FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new LoginFragment()).commit();
```

The errors say

> Can't resolve method 'getActivity()'

on that first line, even though I've seen it in the documentation, and

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'your.project.structure.LoginFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

on the second line where I have `new LoginFragment()`

After hours of googling, trying things and reading documentation, I still have no idea what I'm doing, and I end up going in circles. I also have no idea if I'm even giving enough information, so ask away and I'll do my best to respond accurately.

Comment: make sure your class is extends to `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoginFragment` doesn't override `Fragment` class. This is the problem of the second error.

For the first one, is the code you posted in an `Activity`? Or is it in a `Fragment`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the `LoginFragment` class override the `Fragment` class. I've overridden methods before, but not a whole class (`LoginFragment` does extend `FragmentActivity` btw, if that's important).

Currently it's in a `Fragment`. I do have a branch of this project where everything is an activity, and I get the same error (except for the `new LoginFragment()` error, it gives the same unresolvable message as the `getActivity()` one).

Comment: If it extends `FragmentActivity` it's not a `Fragment`, it's an `Activity`. Change the implementation to `Fragment`. 
If the code is in an `Activity` you don't have to call `getActivity()` as you are in an `Activity` just remove it or go with `this.`

Answer (score 0):

- `LoginFragment()` extend `Fragment`.
- If the code is in an `Activity`, use `this.getSupportFragmentManager()`. If in `Fragment` , use `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I tried doing that as per the suggestion from @Luca Nicoletti, but then it says that `getSupportFragmentManager()` cannot be resolved.